# Netbeans Изменить стандартные комментарии

Tags: netbeans

Как изменить текст лицензии, я нашел.

Поискал в документации, не нашел.

А как изменить стандартные комментарии при создании файла?
Нпример

```
/*
Это нашел как изменить = Текст лицензии
*/
/* 
    Created on : Mar 13, 2017, 11:04:48 PM //   
    Author     : USER  А вот это как???
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел, tools -> Templates , там выбираем для чего именно хотим изменить.